# using min and DATE() in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running an SQL Query and i want to use `min()` and `DATE()`

i tried:

```
and min(DATE(datetime)) = '".date("Y-m-d")."'
```

but that does not work, what should i be using?

the full query i have tried is:

```
select 
  min(datetime) as d, 
  ticketnumber 
from ticket_updates 
where type = 'update' 
and min(DATE(datetime)) = '".date("Y-m-d")."' 
group by ticketnumber
```

i have also tried:

```
select 
  min(datetime) as d, 
  ticketnumber 
from ticket_updates 
where type = 'update' 
and min(datetime) >= '".date("Y-m-d 00:00:00")."' 
and min(datetime) <= '".date("Y-m-d 23:59:59")."'
group by ticketnumber
```

but i get an error saying:

> Invalid use of group function

Comment: what are you looking for ?

Comment: earliest datetime but date only, not date and time

Comment: what is the data type of the column ? and which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: Are you only wanting a single record back?  How about `order by date limit 1` (or `top 1` in sql server)

Comment: Where is the full query? Also which database you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the *earliest* date time, then use a `having` clause:

```
select min(datetime) as d, ticketnumber 
from ticket_updates 
where type = 'update' 
group by ticketnumber
having min(DATE(datetime)) = '".date("Y-m-d")."'
```

These seems rather strange as a construct, because the min is going to get the date you are entering.  All the work is in the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use the `min` function in your where clause.

I've also changed the where to use `between` for readability.

```
select 
  min(datetime) as d, 
  ticketnumber 
from ticket_updates 
where type = 'update' 
and datetime between'".date("Y-m-d 00:00:00")."' 
                and '".date("Y-m-d 23:59:59")."'
group by ticketnumber
```

This code will find the lowest date/time for each ticket number on the date provided.

Check out this [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e32ca/5)

Comment: thats what i want but its returning incorrect rows / not the lowest datetime per ticketnumber

Comment: @user2710234 perhaps you could create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with example data to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: i have tried this but i get an error saying: Invalid use of group function - 

code is

select min(datetime) from ticket_updates where type = 'update' and (datetime) > '2014-11-25 00:00:00' and (datetime) < '2014-11-25 23:59:59' group by ticketnumber

Comment: @user2710234 What is the name of the column that holds the date value?  is it really `datetime`?

Comment: @user2710234 check out this fiddle i created, let me know if it works for you. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e32ca/5

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your query to another:

```
SELECT d, ticketnumber FROM(
  select 
  min(datetime) as d, 
  ticketnumber 
  from ticket_updates 
  where type = 'update' 
  group by ticketnumber
) t
WHERE d between '...' and '...'
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e32ca/9)

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to get the min date you need to have a column to group by. For example,

```
Select id, Min(Date) as Min_date
from mytable group by id
```

Can you provide more details so that we can try to resolve this?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but a lot of things have changed as information has been revealed.  Be sure to keep up with the changes to avoid downvotes.  Best to update or delete your answer at this point.  HTH!

Comment: downvoter, with `not an answer` flag. This for comments discussion, not for answers. And: group by pk? really? what wrong with ticketnumber?